# How to install mathplotlib - python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm using sublime text 2 to run python 2.7. I have downloaded and installed mathplotlib. When I type the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/HP v190b/Python - Squash Coursework/squashFINAL.py", line 212, in <module>
    import matplot.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplot.pyplot
```

Any ideas why? I'm using a Mac!

Comment: did you try `import matplotlib.pyplot`?  (notice the "`lib`")

Comment: yes sorry, just edited the question

Comment: 99% chance it is installed in a location not on your pythonpath. I am not familiar with mac setups, but it should be a simple google to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the dependencies, sometimes you need to install some dependencies so that you can import certain module, take a look at this link http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html